# Create rpm for self-compiled glibc

Tags: yum, rpm, glibc

I have successfully compiled glibc-2.28 and want to know how to package it into an rpm that is identical(except code) to a centos package as created for centos 7 distro.

If I had a template for how the centos package maintainers create their distros, that would probably be sufficient. All that I can find in the centos source repos is package contents(code) but not the rpm build files.

Comment: Get src.rpm for glibc.

Comment: Welcome, what is your business-related question or issue? Have you done any essential research?

Comment: Switching glibc sounds like a disaster waiting to happen

Comment: The *proper* way would probably be to get the srpm, apply your patch, and build it. This [is documented by the CentOS project](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos(2f)RebuildSRPM.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not build your own libc, definitely not one based on a soon to be end of life distro. You will not have the time to responsibly maintain it and untangle its impacts on *all* your software.

Rather, rebuild applications on a newer, supported distro. In the case of Red Hat family, as of now in the year 2024, EL9 if you are able and EL8 if you must. Ideally you have the source code to help with this rebuild project, or at least some maintainer does. If not, replace the software with something supported.

Note that CentOS Stream is not identical to RHEL. If you want RHEL binary compatibility, use source code from RHEL or its rebuild distros.

Start from existing source rpms of applications, edit the rpm spec to increment its release number, and do a clean rebuild in with the mock tool. With an EL9 target. In easy cases, software rebuilds with no changes.